# Application throwing 500 error when image not found instead of 404

Tags: java, jboss7.x, atg

We have shifted from Jboss 6 to Jboss 7.2.9 and we observed one changes in the site.

Earlier when we were not find an image then we were getting 404 error which is acceptable but after moving to Jboss 7.2.9 now we see it's throwing a 500 error which is an issue.

We haven't change anything in code or in web.xml but hard to understand why this is happening.

Note : Our site is deployed in Java ATG

Thank You.

---

Code in web.xml

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>error500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Server log error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: JBWEB004036: File **imagePath**(Any Image) not found
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.doErrorDispatch(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:204) [undertow-servlet-2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276) [undertow-servlet-2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) [undertow-servlet-2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133) [undertow-servlet-2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) [undertow-servlet-2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.30.SP4-redhat-00001]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)

Comment: Without any code or logs or research we can't help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.